# WSL, bash, Docker: "unable to prepare context"

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

While following [this tutorial](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/docker-tutorial-for-beginners/video/docker-images-vs-docker-containers) using WSL & bash I get:

```
~$ cd /tmp/docker-nginx-test

/tmp/docker-nginx-test$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 0 george george 4096 Apr 21 06:27 .
drwxrwxrwt 0 root   root   4096 Apr 21 06:02 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 george george   18 Apr 21 06:27 Dockerfile

/tmp/docker-nginx-test$ docker.exe build /tmp/docker-nginx-test
unable to prepare context: path "/tmp/docker-nginx-test" not found
```

also:

```
/tmp/docker-nginx-test$ docker.exe build  ./Dockerfile
unable to prepare context: path "./Dockerfile" not found
/tmp/docker-nginx-test$ ls -al ./Dockerfile
-rwxrwxrwx 1 george george 18 Apr 21 06:27 ./Dockerfile
```

with:

```
$ docker.exe --version
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24
```

Comment: Have you tried `docker.exe build .`?

Comment: @Cyclonecode With `docker.exe build .` I get `unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFileAttributesEx G:\Documents\workspace\docker\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.` The file `Dockerfile` does not exist at that directory.

Comment: @Cyclonecode With the (not quite infinite) monkey approach, this works: `/tmp/docker-nginx-test$ docker.exe build ./tmp/Dockerfile`. It is not at all clear to me why. In Windows, there exists `G:\Documents\workspace\docker\tmp\Dockerfile`. It appears that somehow I've created a symlink from `/tmp/docker-nginx-test` to `/tmp/Dockerfile`. Not at all clear how I did that. Time to review history.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem comes from the tutorial's instruction `mkdir /tmp/docker-nginx-test && cd $_`.  Had I been working in a Linux environment all would be well. Using WSL & bash I was not working in a directory that was explicitly ` /tmp/docker-nginx-test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above tutorial, a successful approach with WSL & bash is to do:

```
$ mkdir docker-nginx-test
$ cd docker-nginx-test
$ docker-compose.exe down
$ docker-compose.exe build --pull --no-cache
$ docker-compose.exe -f docker-compose.yml up -d --remove-orphans
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem was that I was using the Linux path only (`/home/user/project/Dockerfile`) but I had to use the Windows file-path from where my WSL distro was stored, and then take the the path under rootfs and escape the backslashes. Like this:

```
docker.exe build -t 
C:\\Users\\username\\Ubuntu1804WSL\\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_1804.2018.817.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc\\rootfs\\home\\user\\scratch\\project
```

That fixed it for me.